# correct bash parsing of unquoted file arguments containing backslash spaces instead of quotes

Tags: bash, parsing, tabs, arguments, filenames

This is pretty basic, I guess I'm missing something really obvious...

The following sequence should explain it:

```
$ cat read_file_names.sh 
#!/bin/bash
for i in $@ ; do 
    echo "$i"
done
$ touch "filename has many spaces" 
$ ./read_file_names.sh filename\ has\ many\ spaces 
filename
has
many
spaces
```

ideally, the command line will have quotes around the filename as in:

```
$ ./read_file_names.sh "filename\ has\ many\ spaces"
```

The problem is that when allowing bash to auto-complete the filename (by hitting tab), the file name is left unquoted. Instead, it has a backslash-space "\ " to signal a space. I understand I can add quotes manually, but that would be tedious and a poor user experience.

I'm looking for a solution which assigns the *entire* file name to the for-loop variable, so that the output looks something like this:

```
$ ./read_file_names.sh filename\ has\ many\ spaces 
filename has many spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslashes are working. It's your debugging printer that's wrong:

```
for i in $@ ; do
```

That needs to be:

```
for i in "$@"; do
```

Otherwise, the argument string is inserted unquoted into the for expression and then word-split.

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. I see it's mentioned in the bash manpage:
@ Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the  expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...